# Javascript ES6 generator async

Tags: javascript, generator, ecmascript-6

I need to run generator async (I need to have result in console 1,2,3,4,5 cause now I have 4,1,2,3,5) any one can help me? I need run task and wait when previous task is finished before it run next task. I need to use (if possible: only) generators (or generator + promise?)

Here my code

```
/*jshint esnext: true */
function show(msg) {
  var _msg = msg;
  setTimeout(function() { console.log(_msg);}, 2000);
}

function show2(msg) {
  console.log(msg);
}

var stack = [];

// add some function to stack
stack.push(function() { show(1); });
stack.push(function() { show(2); });
stack.push(function() { show(3); });
stack.push(function() { show2(4); });
stack.push(function() { show(5); });

function* generator1() {
  for(var key of stack) {
    yield key();
  }
}
var gen = generator1();
gen.next();
gen.next();
gen.next();
gen.next();
gen.next();
```

Comment: Try to write a solution without generators (using only callbacks or promises) first. Then we might be able to show you how to incorporate generators in that picture - because on their own, generators are not asynchronous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done purely with a generator. Here's an example of one approach, in which we move the `.next()` into the timeout itself in order to ensure it doesn't occur early. Additionally, the generator now returns the function off the stack instead of executing it, because you can't call `.next()` on a generator from within the execution of the generator itself.

It's worth noting here that this probably isn't the way I'd do this 'in the wild'; I'd include promises. But you asked if it could be done with just a generator - the answer is 'yes'.

```
function show(msg) {
  var _msg = msg;
  setTimeout(function() { 
      console.log(_msg);
      execute();
  }, 2000);
}

function show2(msg) {
  console.log(msg);
  execute();
}

var stack = [];

function execute() {
  var fn = gen.next().value;
  if (fn) fn();
}

// add some function to stack
stack.push(function() { show(1); });
stack.push(function() { show(2); });
stack.push(function() { show(3); });
stack.push(function() { show2(4); });
stack.push(function() { show(5); });

function* generator1() {
  for(var key of stack) {
    yield key;
  }
}
var gen = generator1();
execute();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/smmccrohan/k271gz7o/

Comment: generators on top of callbacks, to be precise :-)

Answer (score 2):

There are many "task running" functions for this, you can even write your own. But you will have to use Promises for this, and not `setTimeout`. Here is a quick example:

```js
function delay (ms, val) {
  return new Promise(function (res) {
    setTimeout(res, ms || 1000, val || Math.random());
    });
  }

function* run () {
  yield delay();
  console.log(yield delay());
  yield delay();
  console.log('foo'); // sync calls anywhere in between
  console.log(yield delay());
  }

function async(gen){ "use strict";
    gen = gen();
    return Promise.resolve().then(function cont(a){
        var n = gen.next(a),
            v = Promise.resolve(n.value);
        if(n.done) return v; // a `return`
        return n.value.catch(gen.throw.bind(gen)).then(cont);
    });
};

async(run);
```

Basically, we call the `next` method of the generator, wait for it to complete, and then fire the `next` method again, and recurse until generator halts.

Bluebird has a more fault-proof function called `Promise.coroutine`.

Task.js: http://taskjs.org/ provides a function specially for this.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

You need a way for your functions to tell when they are finished. Promises are a good way to solve that problem.

I will stick to your original code as much as I can:

```
function show(msg) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve){
    var _msg = msg;
    setTimeout(function() { console.log(_msg); resolve(_msg);}, 2000);
  });
}

function show2(msg) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve){
    console.log(msg);
    resolve(msg);
  });
}

var stack = [];

// add some function to stack
stack.push(function() { return show(1); });
stack.push(function() { return show(2); });
stack.push(function() { return show(3); });
stack.push(function() { return show2(4); });
stack.push(function() { return show(5); });

function* generator1() {
  for(var key of stack) {
    yield key();
  }
}

var gen = generator1();
gen.next().value.then(function(){
  gen.next().value.then(function(){
     gen.next().value.then(function(){
        gen.next().value.then(function(){
           gen.next();
        });
    });
  });
});
```

Of course it looks ugly, and can be improved. As mentioned in the other answer, there are task runners and flow control libs, such as [task.js](http://taskjs.org/) , [gen-run](https://github.com/creationix/gen-run), and [co](https://github.com/tj/co).

With `co`, the last part would be:

```
co(generator1);
```